# check if all rows have column not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having problem with getting information if all rows grouped by COLUMN A have not null in COLUMN B I provide my query below:

```
select 
    z.zamodb_id, zp.zamodbpoz_id, zp.data_planowana 
from 
    zamodbpoz zp
inner join 
    zamodb z on z.zamodb_id = zp.zamodb_id
inner join 
    sys_dok_stan ds on z.zamodb_id = ds.dok_id
inner join 
    cechwytw cw on cw.wytwor_id = zp.wytwor_id and cw.katparam_id = 52
left join 
    dyspozycje_partii dp on dp.dok_poz_id = zp.zamodbpoz_id
left join 
    (select 
         zp.zamodbpoz_id, isnull(wzp.ilosc, 0) ilosc 
     from  
         zamodb z
     inner join 
         zamodbpoz zp on z.zamodb_id = zp.zamodb_id
     left join 
         alokdok a on a.doknad_poz_id = zp.zamodbpoz_id and a.typdok_nad = 11
     left join 
         dokument_wydania_zewn wz on a.dokpod_id = wz.dokwydzew_id and wz.statusdwz <> 3
     left join 
         dokument_wydania_zewn_poz wzp on wz.dokwydzew_id = wzp.dokwydzew_id
     group by 
         zp.zamodbpoz_id,wzp.ilosc) ile_wz on zp.zamodbpoz_id = ile_wz.zamodbpoz_id
where 
    ds.dok_stan_idn = 'PLANISTA' and z.statzamodb = 1
group by 
    zp.zamodbpoz_id, zp.ilpotw, zp.ilzreal, 
    dp.ilosc, ile_wz.ilosc, z.zamodb_id, zp.data_planowana
having 
    zp.ilpotw - zp.ilzreal - isnull(dp.ilosc, 0) - isnull(ile_wz.ilosc, 0) > 0
```

And there is just a piece of result:

[image: piece of result]

How to check if `z.zamodb = 446341` having value in 3rd column in all rows ? As you can see on the picture there is one row with `NULL` and I would like to skip all records with `z.zamodb_id = 446341`.

Comment: Can you some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying Tim's logic for all rows with the same `zamodb_id` using *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
with cte as 
 ( select z.zamodb_id,zp.zamodbpoz_id,zp.data_planowana
      ,count(*)                 over (partition by z.zamodb_id) as cntStar
      ,count(zp.data_planowana) over (partition by z.zamodb_id) as cntCol
   from zamodbpoz zp
   ....
 )
select *
from cte
where cntStar = cntCol
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your current `HAVING` clause is doing, or if it's even working, but here is the logic you can use:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(zp.data_planowana)
```

Since `COUNT` does not include `NULL` values, and `COUNT(*)` always returns the total number of records in the group, the above equality can only be true if the `zp.data_planowana` column has no `NULL` values.